# Unable to send local file to activeMQ

Tags: blob, activemq-classic

I'm using activeMQ and I need to write images to it. For some reason I can specify an image on the web, but if I try to use a local image then it doesn't work.

Here's my code

```
public class AMQmessageSender{

  static String ActiveMQ_URL = "tcp://UTMSA603:61616";
  static String localPicURL = "path_to_my_local_file";

  public static void main(String[] args){
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQ_URL);

    Connection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    ActiveMQSession session = (ActiveMQSession) connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

    Destination destination = session.createQueue(“blobs”);

    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    producer.setDeliveryMode (DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);

    File file = new File(localPicURL);
    BlobMessage message = session.createBlobMessage(file);
    producer.send(message);

    session.close();
    connection.close();
  }
}
```

And here is the error I keep getting

[image]

Now I read something about how you need an http or ftp server to make this work, but on [ActiveMQ's website](http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html) it looks like they're just using file locations in their local file example. Do I really need to setup an http or ftp server to send a local file through ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes when using blob you need to use an out of band transport, see more details at: http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html

Then you need to setup that chosen such as ftp,http etc and add the dependencies to the client classpath.

But also remember a message broker is not a database or file system to store big files. Use something else for that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you explain to me what exactly is meant by "out of band transport"?  I get that it can be http, ftp or scp, but why, and what would be an example of "in band" transport?

Comment: non blob messages like regular text or bytes messages. If you files is not so big just send them as regular text or bytes messages

Comment: Oh I see now, I thought all binary messages had to be blob messages, thanks for helping me understand.